# Button layout_alignParentRight does not work on the first loop?

Tags: java, android, button

I add dynamically viewflipper and on each view I add multiple views one of which is a RelativeLayer containg two buttons - one to go on the left on to the right of the layer.

it works for all loops , but not for the first, where both buttons stay one atop another on the left.
Anyone with helpful advice appreciated.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.slider_holder);



for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {

ViewGroup np = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.nexpre);
LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.flipper_slides, parent, false);

RelativeLayout next_prev =(RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.next_prev, l, false);


for (int k = 0; k< temp1.length; k++) { 
ViewGroup nested_parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.nested_slider_holder);  
LinearLayout nl=(LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.nested_flipper_slides, nested_parent, false);

TextView temp_tv1 =(TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.nested_flipper_tv, nl, false);

temp_tv1.setText(temp[i]+" "+temp1[k]);
nl.addView(temp_tv1);
ff.addView(nl); 

}

next_prev.addView(nested_prev);
next_prev.addView(nested_next);

l.addView(ff);
l.addView(next_prev);
f.addView(l);
}
```

This is the next_prev.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/nexpre"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="-50dip" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the nested_prev.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Prev" >

</Button>
```

And this is the nested_next.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Next" >

</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that on the first loop the button that was supposed to go all the way to the right, did not. For all other loops after the first it works but not for the first.

I added this line to the code:

```
    if(i==0){

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE); 
        next_prev.getChildAt(1).setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

for the first loop I do "ALIGN PARENT RIGHT" programmatically with layout params.

Anyway if anyone could explain the reason why the first loop behaves differently by the others I would appreciate.